# What is wrong that shows "Use of undeclared type" after adding an function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, undeclared-identifier

I am writing a swift project mixing with others' project writing in Objective-C. 
I have already used a bridging header file. And it works.

I am now using some function from others' project. Before I add the functions, which have been declared in .h file. It works: 
[image]

However, when I add the function:

```
func SACalendar(calendar: SACalendar!, didSelectDate day: Int32, month: Int32, year: Int32) {

}
```

Errors occur:

> Use of undeclared type 'SACalendar'!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you define a method with the same name `SACalendar`
as an existing class. This instance method   "hides" the class definition
within `class Calendar`.

Renaming `func SACalendar(...)` should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R. But this is the function that declared previously in SACalendar.h file: `-(void) SACalendar:(SACalendar*)calendar didSelectDate:(int)day month:(int)month year:(int)year;`  And I just simply want to use the didSelectDate function.

Comment: @elvislkm: OK, I see,it is the SACalendarDelegate method. The problem is that these delegate methods start with "SACalendar" and therefore hide the class itself in Swift. This is quite unusual, normally method names start with a lower-case letter. One solution would be to *rename* all SACalendarDelegate methods to `-(void) saCalendar:...`. I haven't found another solution yet.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I've renamed all the SACalendar delegate methods. And it works!!! Yes, it is quite weird that the methods and class are having the same name.